# ElasticSearch Query : Query must match at least one of multiple values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need help for an ElasticSearch Query, I need to combine SHOULD and MUST but I don't know how to do it :

Here is an example of a query I wanna do :

```
    ap_code= ["ta", "All"] (OR condition)

    AND

    ra_code= ["ph", "All"] (OR condition)

    AND

    city = ["London"]
```

This is the query, but it gets all results from the ES

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "city" : {
            "query" : "London",
            "slop" : 0,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should" : [
      {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "ra_code" : {
            "query" : "ph",
            "slop" : 0,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "ra_code" : {
            "query" : "All",
            "slop" : 0,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "ap_code" : {
            "query" : "All",
            "slop" : 0,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "ap_code" : {
            "query" : "ta",
            "slop" : 0,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Im using Java API to create the query (JDK 11)

Any help please ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use should query inside a must clause like below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "city": {
              "query": "London",
              "slop": 0,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ra_code": {
                    "query": "ph",
                    "slop": 0,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ra_code": {
                    "query": "All",
                    "slop": 0,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ap_code": {
                    "query": "ta",
                    "slop": 0,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ap_code": {
                    "query": "All",
                    "slop": 0,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For Java api , you can try something like below

```
BoolQueryBuilder first = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field1, value1))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field2, value2));

BoolQueryBuilder second= QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field1, value1))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field2, value2));


BoolQueryBuilder filter = new BoolQueryBuilder()
    .must(first)
    .must(second);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
Ive tried doing this (embbeded must and should) but I don't know how using Java API. Any idea ?

Comment: @Lina I have added a sample

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Exactly what I was looking for :)